# In VBA how do I get the combobox to remove the item after unchecking the checkbox?

Tags: excel, vba

A bit of a background before I explain my issue. This worksheet contains multiple checkboxes which lists various machine parts. Another sheet on the same file contains the Part Caption and the Part Number.

What the VBA code does is look at what checkboxes have been checked, then make reference to the Part number sheet, grab the Part name and Number and add it to the combo list.

The code works as intended, however the problem lies in duplicates. For example, if someone checks and unchecks one checkbox, the combobox will have multiple entries of the same part.

This is what I would like some assistance. Basically what I would like to achieve is when someone unchecks a checkbox, that part name and number be removed from the combobox. The code is below:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
     Dim SearchString As String

     Dim SearchRange As Range

     SearchString = CheckBox1.Caption

     Dim ans As String

     Set SearchRange = Sheets("Table of Part Numbers").Range("A39:A45").Find(SearchString, 
     LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

     If SearchRange Is Nothing Then MsgBox SearchString & "  Not Found": Exit Sub

ans = SearchRange.Offset(0, 1).Value

ComboBox1.AddItem ans

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: I cannot use Option button.

Comment: After any change Clear the list the run the macro to rebuild it based on selected check boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself after debugging and learning VBA further, so I guess I'll post the solution myself in case someone ends up needing something similar:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim SearchString As String
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim ans As String
Dim i As Long
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    SearchString = CheckBox1.Caption
    Set SearchRange = Sheets("Table of Part Numbers").Range("A38:A45").Find(SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If SearchRange Is Nothing Then MsgBox SearchString & "  Not Found": Exit Sub
    ans = SearchRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
    ComboBox1.AddItem ans
End If


If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
    SearchString = CheckBox1.Caption
    Set SearchRange = Sheets("Table of Part Numbers").Range("A38:A45").Find(SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If SearchRange Is Nothing Then MsgBox SearchString & "  Not Found": Exit Sub
    ans = SearchRange.Offset(0, 1).Value

For i = ComboBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If ComboBox1.List(i) = ans Then
    ComboBox1.RemoveItem (i)
  End If
Next
End If
End Sub
```